# check parameter values if its null or not, and then initialize the object. is it good idea?

Tags: c#

Currently, I am maintaining a program which is not developed by me, in so many parts of our code we have something like

```
public BookingItemResponse(BookingItem[] BookingItems,Currency="USD", string bookingName=null, string passengerEmail =null)
{
    Request.BookingItem[]=BookingItems;
    if(bookingName!=null) Request.BookingName=bookingName;
    if(passengerEmail!=null) Request.PassengerEmail=passengerEmail;

    return BookingItemResponse
}
```

is it necessary to check the parametes if they are null or not and then initialize my target object ?

what if i simply remove the ifs and just write something like below

```
Request.BookingName=bookingName;
```

note that, request object will be serialized at the end. and the response will be deserialized and return as BookingItemResponse.

which one is more performance optimized ?

Comment: why do you want to remove ifs?!?

Comment: lol :D good question, but it makes our program less readable. some more i want to know in which solution i can gain the highest performance

Comment: What is the value of Request.BookingName if bookingName is null?
What is the default value ?

Comment: the default value is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public BookingItemResponse(BookingItem[] BookingItems,Currency="USD", string bookingName=null, string passengerEmail =null)
{

    Request.BookingItem[]=BookingItems;

    //If the default value is null you can remove the ifs
    Request.BookingName=bookingName;
    Request.PassengerEmail=passengerEmail;

    //else you can use the ?? operator
    Request.BookingName=bookingName ?? "Your default value";
    Request.PassengerEmail=passengerEmail ?? "Your default value";

    return BookingItemResponse;
}
```

In any case you don't have to worry about the performance of an if statement in your code
(unless that code is called millions of times)

Comment: check @Behzad's comment. default value is null.

Comment: yes the function will be called so many times through our program and this is not the only function. so you suggest me to remove the ifs right ?

Comment: @Behzad If null is a valid value for Request.BookingName (and the default value is null) ,yes remove the ifs.no need for the extra check

Comment: @GeorgeVovos as i said the Request object will be serialized at the end, so the null values will be null xml tags. and thats alright

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is not to check for `null`s. Instead - create overload for this method without `bookingName` and `passengerEmail`. This will make your code more flexible and more clear.

As for me, in your case you will not get any performance rise in any case.

Comment: This is a good idead,but if you do this don't duplicate code on that new function.Just call the original function will the correct arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You will always need the if-statements, any caller can still pass null to your method. Default values are only used if the parameters are omitted.

```
BookingItem[] items = null; // From somewhere...
new BookingItemResponse(items, Currency: null);
```

This will still pass a null value to `BookingItemResponse` for the `Currency` parameter, while `bookingName` and `passengerEmail` will be assigned their default values.